# (Kivy) Updating a class variable

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have been writing a code using kivy. Here I am trying to take the input from the user in the "EighthWindow" and trying to get that variable in the "SecondWindow" for a label. My approach was to define UN as a class variable and then update when the username is entered by calling the function. Then I get the updated value of UN in the second class and plug it in. But UN does not get updated.

I am new to kivy and the overall concept of classes and objects as well. Any kind of constructive criticism and help is appreciated. Here are the shortened codes:

Python File

```
class EighthWindow(Screen): 
    username= ObjectProperty(None)
    password= ObjectProperty(None)
    UN=""
    def change_var(self):
        EighthWindow.UN=self.username.text
        print(EighthWindow.UN)
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    n=EighthWindow.UN
    Name=StringProperty(n)
```

Kivy file

```
<EighthWindow>:
    name:"Eighth"
    username:username
    password:password
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: username
            hint_text:"Username"
            size_hint:0.6,9/40-0.1
            pos_hint:{"top":4/5-0.1,"x":0.2}
            multiline:False
        Button:
            size_hint:0.6,9/40-0.1
            pos_hint:{"top":2/5-0.06,"x":0.2}
            text:"Login"
            on_press:
                root.change_var()
                app.root.current="second"

<SecondWindow>:
    name:"second"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:root.Name
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0.75}
            size_hint:0.3,0.25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with your code is using the class variable `UN`. Since that variable is not a `Property`, other variables (or `Properties`) will not get automatically updated when it changes. But you can bypass the `UN` variable by changing your class definitions like this:

```
class EighthWindow(Screen):
    username= ObjectProperty(None)
    password= ObjectProperty(None)
    def change_var(self):
        self.manager.get_screen('second').Name = self.username.text


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    Name=StringProperty('')
```

This eliminates the `UN` variable and directly sets the `Name` `Property`, which automatically updates the `Label` in `SecondWindow`.